# DropDownList in Gridview Templatefield, toggle Visibility with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a problem trying to hide/show an ASP Dropdownlist depending on certain criteria. I'm trying to do this with jQuery to avoid postbacks.

The code below is an altered and scaled down version of a much bigger project. The concept is to click the linkbutton (lnkBtn) in the gridview (gv1) which then displays the dropdownlist (ddlTS). Once a selection has been made in the dropdownlist, jQuery function fires making the dropdownlist invisible again. This all appears to work fine until a selection on another row is made. Both the dropdownlists on the original row and the new row become visible.

I imagine there is probably a much better way of doing it but I cannot seem to make it work. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

```
<div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnRow" runat="server" />
    <asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="gv1_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TimeZone">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
                        CommandName="PostTimestamp" Text='<%# bind("edw_tz") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTS" runat="server" CssClass="ddl_None">
                        <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>

protected void gv1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "PostTimestamp")
    {
        int row = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        ((DropDownList)gv1.Rows[row].FindControl("ddlTS")).CssClass = "ddlclass_Inline";
        hdnRow.Value = row.ToString();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id*=gv1][id*=ddlTS]").change(function () {
        var row = $('#hdnRow').val();
        $('[id$=gv1_ddlTS_' + row + ']').removeClass('ddl_Inline').addClass('ddl_None');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you using Row-command Event..? for just getting the index..? . Its an unnecessary post back. You can get the index from client side itself by using the script like this onclick of link button.

```
var index = $("#gv1").closest('tr').prevAll().length - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

add CssClass names to both `LinkButton` as well as `DropDownList` in `GridView` template
for example we assigned

```
CssClass="lbtnGV"
```

for `LinkButton`
and

```
CssClass="ddlGV"
```

for `DropDownList`

now jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.lbtnGV').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('.ddlGV').show(0);
});
$('.ddlGV').change(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide(0);
});
});
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure but what I have understood:

By default the dropdowns are hidden and the same are visible on click of linkbutton. You want to hide the dropdown whenever there is a change in selection of the dropdown. But when you select one dropdown of say row 1, it works fine, but when you do the same with the next linkbutton of next row, this time the previous dropdown also becomes visible with the actual candidate dropdown (that should be visible).

So, if this is what you want and what is being done, I guess there is a problem with adding or removing css classes in the dropdown that makes them visible or invisible.

Here is what I have coded, and hope it would help you

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2CV25/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.btnLnk').click(function(){ //btnLink is cssclass for linkbutton
    var i=0;
    // iterate through all dropdown to hide them
    $(this).closest("#tblGrid").find("tr").each(function(index, obj){ //tblGrid is id of gridview
        $(obj).find("select").hide();
    });

    //make the actual visible
    $(this).next("select").show();
});

// Again iterate to hide all the dropdown in selection change of a dropdown
$("select").change(function(){
    $(this).closest("#tblGrid").find("tr").each(function(index, obj){
        $(obj).find("select").hide();
    });
});
});
```